# Перезагрузка страницы при клике на <button>

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Есть блок выше кнопок под названием `<div class="btnxxx">` в котором кнопки и после нажатия они меняются , я бы хотел чтобы была перезагрузка страницы, через AJAX-не умею.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ><button class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-three"  onclick="server_stop('[id]')">Выключить</button></div>
```

Сам `div "btnxx"` находится в `xsss.html` (Может с AJAX кто-то поможет)

Нашёл JS который отвечает функции

```
function server_stop(id)
{
wait = true;

loading(1);

$('#status').html('Выполняется...');

$.getJSON(home+'servers/section/action/id/'+id+'/action/stop',
function(data)
{
    wait = false;

    $.each(data, function(i, val)
    {
        if(i == 'e')
            bootbox.dialog('<h3 class="red">Ошибка</h3>'+val,
                [{
                    "label" : "OK",
                    "class" : "btn-small btn-primary",
                }]
            );

        update_info(id, false);
        update_status(id, false);
        update_resources(id, false);

        loading(0)
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Уже пробовал- не обновляет.

Comment: http://www.codething.ru/ajax.php  здесь есть ответ

Comment: Сначала я затупил и написал `<a href="#">`, потом исправил на `/xsss.html` , но есть проблема. У меня с тегом `a` очень много чего связано, оно эту кнопку ... Убрать не смогу

Comment: Если вы знаетесь на AJAX, вы бы могли бы помочь? Я обновил и вопрос и ответ. Заработало, но не до конца.

Comment: я же ссылку дал - то что я знаю , мало чем отличается от примеров с того сайта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть ещё один вариант, то что я и искал, перезагрузка страницы при клике на `button`.
Таким же способом как тот что выше вставляем `setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 5000)`

у меня получилось вот так:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-three"   onclick="server_stop('[id]') ; setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 5000);">Выключить</button></div>
```

Где 5000 - это таймер в миллисекундах

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ><button class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-three"   onclick="server_stop('[id]') ; location.href='/xsss.html';">Выключить</button></div>
```

А если быть более точным то добавил 2 событие при клике
`onclick="server_stop('[id]') ; location.href='/xsss.html';`
А если ещё более точным то в кнопке же было свойство `onclick`,
 тоесть `onclick="server_stop('[id]')"`, я добавил в скобки `; location.href='/xsss.html'`.
 Где `/xsss.html` URL куда направлять.